# Problema al armar una grilla de imagenes

Tags: css, css3, imagen

Quiero armar una galería de imágenes, pero el problema que tengo es que las imágenes la sube el usuario y puede ser de cualquier tamaño, y quiero que sea una grilla perfecta (columnas de mismo tamaño)

No consigo hacer esto con css ni encontré una librera.

Alguien tendrá un ejemplo / librería ?

Comment: Para eso vas a tener que recortar las imágenes todas al mismo tamaño

Answer (score 1):

esto se trata de stilos yo lo haria asi

**Css** para estilos de las imagenes

```
#img{

   width:400px;
   height:400px;
   max-height:400px;
   max-width:400px;
}
#img img{

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-height:150px;
    max-width:150px;

}
```

**imagenes**

```
<img src="">
<img src="">
<img src="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vale, interpreto grilla como cuadrícula (http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?key=grilla). En ese caso, supondré que deseas que las celdas de tu grilla tengan cierto ancho y cierto alto.

Para lograr esto puedes usar una flexbox para montar la grilla.

Las imágenes se pueden ajustar con CSS (aprovechando que width: auto y height: auto garantizan mantener la proporción de la imagen).

Te he preparado un JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1j53bqta/14/

Nota: Te recomiendo que limites el tamaño máximo de las imágenes. Si no lo haces el tiempo de carga de tu página se incrementará considerablemente. Otra opción es reducir su tamaño en el servidor.